# DotNet 5.0 Swagger is not loading in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, swagger, azure-appservice

i have a web api which is created using dotnet 5.0 and deployed to Azure App Service, It is running and swagger loads successful, but in Azure App Service the swagger is not loading also throws 404 error but API data loads successfully.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Check your `Startup.cs` file and the `Configure()` method.
If you created a new .NET 5 project with Swagger automatically configured then it may only be enabled in the development environment.
Check if your code looks something like this:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Lotus.API.Integration v1"));
}
```

Move the Swagger configuration lines outside the `if` statement and that should allow it to load in Azure (i.e. outside of your IDE).

Comment: @Vignesh -- This should be accepted as the answer at this point as I've tried the answer myself and can verify it works.

Comment: Spot on!! This is new since NET 5.0 project template